# What kind of beetle is this (found on landing windowsill)?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image][image][image][image] found this beetle on my landing windowsill, would like to know what it is, very small, this was a zoomed picture on my phone.

Comment: Please provide your location. Also, please add an aproximate size if possible

Comment: Thanks, in the UK and 3mm.  Found another one yesterday, same windowsill, I've uploaded a couple more pictures.

Comment: After researching I think it's a furniture beetle or biscuit beetle?

Comment: @Angel if by "furniture or biscuit beetle" you mean a species of _Anobiidae_ you're probably right; the third photo down shows (admittedly somewhat blurrily) that the last three antennal segments are longer than the others, which is characteristic of that family.  Which species IN that family I can't help you with; I don't know the British fauna.